# jquery: dynamically appending li items to ul then adding click, but click runs through each li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I may be approaching this wrong as I am learning but I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong here (probably simple mistake but I am having trouble). So I am trying to have a  within the markup, a button click that allows selection from dialog and the submit button on the dialog includes call to custom function that does some logic then appends string to the  like:

```
buildListElementItem += "<li>something</li>";
$("#my-list").append(buildListElementItem);
```

then bind click because i need each of these list items to be representative of a selection panel type thing

```
$("#my-list li").bind('click', function () {
   //processing stuff
});
```

everything works fine but if I add more than one item to this list (one after another) and you click a single item, it rolls through each one, which confused me because there is no each and I think this should only add it to a single item....

so there is a bunch more to this function/etc but I think my approach right here is wrong??

I have tried modifying the selector to like a class that I add in the string for the li, I have tried using .on, .live, .delegate or anything I could find instead of bind click.

Perhaps this is simple approach type error to trying to perform this but I would great appreciate any help, advice, etc on this.

EDIT: just adding more for clarification

Dialog allows users to select item from select/drop down, and button click (jquery ui) has function that calls below idea to add the item to a list element, which serves as selection panel. So they can populate items needed on panel, then click each item to populate and associate data with that item.

```
function addNewListItem(passedType)
{
    var buildListElementItem = "<li>" + passedType + "</li>";
    $("#my-list").append(buildListElementItem);
    $("#my-list li").bind('click', function () {
       otherStuff();
});
```

if I do the above I am guessing that this cause every element to get binded over and over again? not sure, but this works with the exception that when I click a single li item on that panel, it processes for all li items on the panel (otherStuff function). So I think from the examples I am starting to understand the issue or why this won't work, but how would I approach what I am trying to do then? always appreciated guys!
}

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this problem. I have a fiddle here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwC7P/). Though i should probably point out that your first line `$("my-list").append....`**my-list** is missing a **#**

Comment: yeah that is a typo in the post....will correct. thanks

Comment: which jquery version is used

Comment: jquery 1.6.2 is being used because of library dependancy

Comment: do you bind the event handler after each `$("#my-list").append(buildListElementItem);`

Comment: yes that is what I was trying to do

Comment: That edit helps. You are binding previous elements multiple times as mentioned below by @Evren Kuzucuoglu . You will have to bind just that specific list item as Evren suggests.

Comment: so that not only fixes my problem, but it makes sense as well from context/learning perspective which helps me even more. thanks for taking the time to help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "there is no each", you omit that `$("#my-list li")` is a jQuery selector, i.e. it returns all the elements that match the expression: in this case, all the li items within the child tree of #my-list.
Thus, when you call bind, it is going to bind to each li item that has already been added to the element.

What you are looking for is something along this:

```
buildListElementItem = $("<li>something</li>"); //constructs a jquery object you can bind to
buildListElementItem.bind('click', function () {
   //processing stuff
});
$("my-list").append(buildListElementItem);
```

This way, you bind before the element has been added.

Comment: I assume his `buildListelementItem` is a string type and not a jQuery object so you can't call `.bind()` on it. But you make a good point that he could have previously been binding events to older items and then double binding. In which case he can call an `.unbind()` method.

Comment: Oh yes I hadn't seen he was using strings and not jQuery object. Will edit post accordingly using jquery element constructor.

Comment: I'm stuck developing on a system still using jQuery 1.6 and using live to bind events was not possible. After hours of searching (and failing) to implement using .live, I finally found your solution and it works a treat! Upvotes for you, sir!